# Manage emails with ElasticSearch in Node.js

Tags: node.js, email, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I use ElasticSearch v7. I need to configure ElasticSearch for searching emails. I read much information about different types of analyzers which I need to use in ElasticSearch for fixing this problem. But there is no any articles related with Node.js. I use NPM module `elasticsearch 16.3.0`. 
Here my code for creating mapping

```
async function createUserMapping () {
    const textType = {type: 'text'};
    const keywordType = {type: 'keyword'};
    const mapping = {
      properties: {
        lastName: {...textType, boost: FIELD_PRIORITIES.LASTNAME},
        firstName: {...textType, boost: FIELD_PRIORITIES.FIRSTNAME},
        username: {...keywordType, boost: FIELD_PRIORITIES.USERNAME},
        email: {
          ...keywordType,
          boost: FIELD_PRIORITIES.EMAIL,
        },
      },
    };
    await client.indices.putMapping({
      ...ES_CONFIG.INDEX,
      ...ES_CONFIG.USER.TYPE,
      body: mapping,
    });
}
```

Please, help me with code to create custom analyzer. If you can, give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
const CustomEmailAnalyzer = 'email_analyzer';

async function addEmailAnalyzer () {
    await client.indices.putSettings({
      ...ES_CONFIG.INDEX,
      body: {
        analysis: {
          analyzer: {
            [CustomEmailAnalyzer]: {
              type: 'custom',
              tokenizer: 'uax_url_email',
              filter: ['lowercase', 'stop'],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
}

async function createUserMapping () {
    const textType = {type: 'text'};
    const keywordType = {type: 'keyword'};
    const mapping = {
      properties: {
        lastName: {...textType, boost: FIELD_PRIORITIES.LASTNAME},
        firstName: {...textType, boost: FIELD_PRIORITIES.FIRSTNAME},
        username: {...keywordType, boost: FIELD_PRIORITIES.USERNAME},
        email: {
          ...textType,
          boost: FIELD_PRIORITIES.EMAIL,
          analyzer: CustomEmailAnalyzer,
        },
      },
    };
    await client.indices.putMapping({
      ...ES_CONFIG.INDEX,
      body: mapping,
    });
}

(async () => {
  await client.indices.close(ES_CONFIG.INDEX);
  await addEmailAnalyzer();
  await client.indices.open(ES_CONFIG.INDEX);
  await createUserMapping();
})();
```